# How to validate sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE

Tags: validation, symfony1, tinymce, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I use symfony 1.4.11. And I have next:

```
$this->widgetSchema['en']['content'] = new sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE(array(
        'width'   => 900,
        'height'  => 300,
          'config' => 'theme_advanced_buttons1 : "cut, copy, paste, images, bold, italic, underline, justifyleft, justifycenter, justifyright , outdent, indent, bullist, numlist, undo, redo, link",
                       theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",            
                       theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
                       theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                       theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                       theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                       theme_advanced_resizing: "false",
                       plugins: "images, paste",
                       '),array('class' => 'tinyMCE',)
    );
```

I need to validte this, I try sfValidatorString ,but it is not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting your widget (an probably neither your validator) correctly. If you want to group/nest widgets you need to embed another form in your container form.

EDIT:

Either you create a new form which has the 'content' widget, which you embed in the parent form like so:

```
$this->embedForm('en', new myContentForm());
```

Alternatively you add the widget like so:

```
$this->widgetSchema['content_en'] = new sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE(...);
```

The specifics really depend on your usecase, and I might suggest you read up on forms here:

http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/ (still relevant for 1.4)